# Is it possible to rewrite this with proper termination?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I can't seem to figure out how to properly terminate these statements..

```
.append("<div class='grid_2'>#{@new_topic.name}</div><div class='grid_3'><a href=\'#{destroy_topic_admin_me_categories_path(:topic => @new_topic.id, :class => 'button delete_topic')}\'</div>")
```

Right now its not closing the last div and anchor tag properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
.append("<div class='grid_2'>#{@new_topic.name}</div><div class='grid_3'><a href=\"#{destroy_topic_admin_me_categories_path(:topic => @new_topic.id, :class => 'button delete_topic')}\"></a></div>")
```

You were missing a > and the using \" is more clear then mixing ' \' with " in my option.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the rest of the `<a href="" />` tag.

You open it with `<a href=....` but never complete the tag with `>text</a>`